# Handling Rails routes/models with belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So this may be more of a convention question, but im writing a todo app to learn how to use rails as an API (Im somewhat intermediate with using rails normally) but this time im using it with React for the front end.

Im making a simple todo app, two models in particular being "Lists" and "ListItems". Lists `has_many` ListItems of course, and a ListItem `belongs_to` a List.

So naturally I have the routes set up like so:

```
      resources :lists do
        resources :list_items
      end
```

Giving me routes similar to: `/api/v1/lists/:list_id/list_items` etc.., However I saw some people doing a similar app set it up like:

```
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :list_items
      resources :lists
    end
```

Which confuses me because how would you handle passing the actual "List" params to the route, when the route itself would not have a `List_id` param?

Or would this more be used for a join table somehow..but you would still have to populate the `List_id` regardless when creating a `list_item` for a specific list correct?

Is there a preferred way of doing this as far as routing goes? (And I suppose creating tables?) Since a `has_many_through` seems not really necessary in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is more to the story, you are doing it the more conventional way. I suggest your can safely disregard that not-nested approach. The only enhancement I suggest is using `shallow: true`, like:

```
namespace :api do 
  namespace :v1 do 
    resources :lists do 
      resources :list_items, shallow: true
    end
  end
end
```

You can read more about shallow nesting in [the guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting).

Comment: I guess why would someone make a join table for something as simple as a todo list? I feel like a join table only makes sense where you have a many to many relationship? In a "Todo" app I feel like Lists would only "have many" List_items and not the other way around?

Comment: Agreed. A join table is difficult to understand in the context of a 1:M relationship. Why would someone make a join table for something as simple as a todo list? I have no idea why people do some of the things they do. I say trust yourself on this one and move on. Your thinking is, IMO, right and clear.